# Divide by 2 for "wasted spark" motorcycle rev counter input

Tags: power, sensor

My motorcycle just got an upgraded ignition timing method. This new method fires the spark plugs twice each cycle which in turn increases the RPM * 2 according to the tachometer.

Is there a way to half the amount of outputs the sensor is sending to the tachometer? Its been a while since I've done anything with electronics so I was looking into d flip flops to throw out every other output but I don't know how hard this is to recreate on a 12-15v system or if there is a simpler solution for my problems.

[image: Wiring diagram, wire in question is red]

[image: Explanation of wiring diagram numbers]

Comment: Do you have any information or schematics regarding the tach sensor? It obviously works off of some firing sequence, but the signal path/level is going to be important.

Comment: The tachometer uses the right ignition coil to determine the RPM. I have some wiring schematics but those would be a pain to scan.

Comment: New dial for the tacho would be the laziest approach given that schematics are such a pain to reproduce.

Comment: Please provide a waveform (measured from an oscilloscope) and explain what you mean by outputs. Do you mean pulses?

Comment: I remembered finding a pdf version of the manual, which isn't that high of a resolution, so added the wire diagram and explanation to the post. @VoltageSpike I think you can call them pulses. I'm not really an electrician and therefor are not familiar with al terms to use.

Comment: @Bort the origonal images were too big, you can switch any imgur image by adding s m l suffix on the end of the filename

Comment: If the dial is just a magnetic coil connected to a spring mass system, it might not be counting pulses at all. It might just be a volt meter which measures the **average** voltage of the pulse train (spring mass acting as a leaky integrator / low pass filter). In that case, you can measure the resistance of the coil (while the dial is stationary so that back em is not present) and add an equal resistance in series so that double the the number of pulses with half the voltage now reads the *correct* rpm. Old school dials are just elctro mechanical voltmeters/ammeters.

Comment: @AJN sounds possible since the motorcycle is from 1984, i'll check soon™.

Comment: @bort Looks good

Comment: @RikPabbruwee I think this question would do better on automotive repair, I could move it over

Comment: @VoltageSpike If you think that fits better go ahead.

Comment: While I realize this is not a shopping question, you could possibly use [the linked product.](https://www.dakotadigital.com/index.cfm/page/ptype=product/product_id=1192/category_id=694/mode=prod/prd1192.htm) NOTE: I have no affiliation with Dakota Digital.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 The part that is giving me problems is [this](https://www.motorparts-online.com/en/moto-guzzi/california-3/1986-1994/meter/201425321) which is the stock tachometer, but it is more related to the fact that ignition coil fire twice per power cycle instead of once.

Comment: Yes and the little box I showed you will convert the signal to 1/2 of what it gets. It's a slick little unit.